# How to check if my windows support 32 bit application to 3GB memory limit

Tags: windows-7

I know to support a process up to 3GB memory limit, a switch in BIOS has to be turned on. Though while the Windows is running, is there any way to check if this 3GB memory addressing is enabled in Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a user process on a 32 bit Windows 7 can max use 2 GB. This is a operating system limit and it has nothing to do with BIOS settings. To enable 3 GB limit on Windows 7 you can use this command on a cmd window running as administrator and then reboot:

```
bcdedit /set IncreaseUserVa 3072
```

To check the current value of IncreaseUserVa use this command on a cmd windows running as administrator and look at Windows Boot Loader section, if you see a IncreaseUserVa entry or not. If not you are using default setting 2GB:

```
bcdedit /enum
```

Comment: Two comments: 1. The increaseuserva option (or /3GB boot.ini option in XP and earlier) applies to x86 Windows. x64 Windows already provides 4 GB virtual address space to 32-bit processes (subject to the next point...). 
2. The application in question must have been linked with the "large address aware" flag in order to use more than 2 GB v.a.s. This applies to both 32- and 64-bit Windows. On 64-bit Windows it even applies to 64-bit apps.